# How to populate the select options from a table in phalcon?

Tags: php, html, phalcon

I have a list containing tags with `id` `name` and `status` in a table and in my Model `TagsStandard` I have this:

```
const STATUS_APPROVED = 1;
const STATUS_DISABLED= 0;

public $id;
public $name;
public $status; 

public static function getAllTag()
{
    $tags = TagsStandard::find(array(
        "status = 'STATUS_APPROVED'",
        "order" => "id"
    ));
}
```

So with this I am getting all the tags. Now at Controller in `indexAction` I have:

```
$tags = TagsStandard::getAllTag();
if ($tags) {
    $this->view->tags = $tags;
    $this->view->name = array("name" => $tags->name->toArray());
}
```

And in the index I have:

```
<select id='user-skills-input' class="select-chosen" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" value="" multiple>
   <?php if(count($tags) > 0): ?>
   <?php foreach($tags->items as $idx => $tag): 
       echo "<option value='" . $tag->id . "'> " . $tag->name . "</option>" ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
</select>
```

The values are not showing up in the options and so can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
echo \Phalcon\Tag::select(array(
    "user-skills-input",
    TagsStandard::find(array(
        "status = 'STATUS_APPROVED'",
        "order" => "id"
    )),
    "using" => array("id", "name")
    );
```

[Phalcon Tags#select](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tags.html#making-select-boxes)